# Can a Sublime Text plugin resize the window?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm brand-new to Python, and I'm trying to write my first plugin for Sublime Text.

I want my plugin to resize the Sublime window, but I can't find any functions to do that in the [Sublime Text API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html).  Basically, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
win = sublime.active_window()
win.setBounds(500, 500)
```

Am I just missing something in the API?  Or perhaps this is something that can be done via standard Python code, without using the Sublime Text API?

Comment: No, this is not possible either via the API or straight Python. It's also a terrible idea from a user's perspective. Why would you want to do that? I have my windows nicely paneled and arranged so I can do my work effectively - I don't want some random plugin resizing things all of a sudden...

Comment: There are all sorts of reasons why somebody might want a plugin to resize the window.  Maybe I want to be able to quickly switch between different pre-defined window sizes using keyboard shortcuts.  Or maybe whenever I open a project, I want to maximize the window.  Or maybe a million other reasons

Comment: Probably you can make an external script and just call it from sublime

Answer (score 2):

You can resize the window with the `resize_window` command. However, I am not sure if you can re-position it through the API.

```
window.run_command('resize_window', {'width': 800, 'height': 600})
```

But, I noticed there is a `hwnd` method on the `window`, which could allow you to use Windows APIs to manipulate the window. To do so from Python, probably you should use the [`PyWin32` module](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#pywin32). Note that `hwnd` returns 0 on Linux, so it seems to not be a cross platform way to retrieve the window handle.

Comment: Tried this with the window param in `on_new_window(self, window)` and `on_new_window_async()` but without any effect.